# restore column while doing operation

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
temp = 
           1             2             3             4             5
7.499 45.109  7.499 45.109  7.499 45.109  7.499 45.109  7.499 45.109
7.499 45.109  7.499 45.109  7.499 45.109  7.499 45.109  7.499 45.109
7.499 45.109  7.499 45.109  7.499 45.109  7.499 45.109  7.499 45.109
7.499 45.109  7.499 45.109  7.499 45.109  7.499 45.109  7.499 45.109
```

`temp.info()` gave me `Columns: 338 entries, 0 to 337`

Then I did the following to split my data:

`df = temp.stack().str.split(' ', expand=True).unstack()`

`df.info()` gave me `Columns: 674 entries, (0, 0) to (1, 337)`

---

## Question:

`0 to 337` and then `1, 337`

WHere is my last column? How to get all of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check your `temp` dataframe for `NaN` value. It is likely that your `temp` has `NaN` values. Default of `stack` dropping `NaN`. To keep `NaN`, you need specify `dropna=False`. Try follows to see if `df.info()` shows 676 entries

```
df = temp.stack(dropna=False).str.split(expand=True).unstack()
df.info()
```

Answer (score 0):

The DataFrame `df` has a `MultiIndex` set as its columns. So, for example, you should be able to access the column that came from the *first* part of original *column 3* with this:

```
df.loc[:, (0, 3)]
```

- The outer level of the columns (`level=0`) takes on the values of 0 or 1, which indicate the first or second part of the result of `str.split()`. (By the way, `str.split()` splits on whitespace by default, so you don't need to specify `' '`)
- The inner (`level=1`) level of the columns contains the values 0 through 337

If you prefer a single-level index in the columns, you can rename the columns of `df` to indicate their origin as follows:

```
df.columns = ['_'.join(map(str, c)) for c in df.columns]
```